# Proof: Quick Sort Is $O(n*logn)$

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

I was given the follow proof:

$$T(n)=n+2T(\frac{n}{2})$$ Will prove that $$T(n)=O(n*logn)$$

For $2:$

$$T(2)=2+2T(1)=2\leq 2*log(2)$$

Assume it is correct for $n-1$ in particular for $\frac{n}{2}$ and prove for $n$:

$$T(n)=n+2T(\frac{n}{2})\leq n+2(c\cdot \frac{n}{2}\cdot log(\frac{n}{2}))=n+cn(log(\frac{n}{2}))=n(1+c(log(\frac{n}{2}))$$

$$=n(1+clog(n))=n+c\cdot nlogn$$

Why is it $O(n*logn)$ and not $O(n)$?

Comment: $\theta({f(n)+g(n))}=\theta(max\{f(n), g(n)\})$

Comment: Because log n is not a constant. Recall $O(cf(n))=O(f(n))$ only if c is a constant. https://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf